# Forticlient on ubuntu 1404 - tunnel running but no IP

Tags: networking, lubuntu, vpn

I am running Lubuntu 14.04 32bit and 64bit on different machines. I use forticlient SSL VPN to connect to my work server with the provided user name and password by the workplace. This setup works fine in windoze. I am unable to get the same to work on Lubuntu.
The forticlient connects with the tunnel running. There is however no IP. Unable to ping any remote server or rdp into any remote server with the tunnel running.
I have tried out the various methods suggested in ask ubuntu earlier with no success.
Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I searched around and found an answer from a fedora user.

After connecting the vpn, with the tunnel running, give the following command in lxterminal:

*mango@mango:~$ ifconfig ppp0 | grep inet*

which returns

*mango@mango:~$ inet addr:10.10.29.2  P-t-P:1.1.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255*

This indicates that the network adapter ppp0 is established and that I need to setup the default gateway to route tunnel traffic.

I then give the following command in lxterminal to setup the routing table.

*mango@mango:~$ sudo route add default gw 10.10.29.2 ppp0*

which returns as

*mango@mango:~$*

with no errors.

Now the tunnel is running and the routing table is established I can proceed to connect into the workplace server.

Thank you.